# Difference between two JavaScript object types

Tags: javascript, prototype

I see objects in JavaScript organized most commonly in the below two fashions.  Could someone please explain the difference and the benefits between the two? Are there cases where one is more appropriate to the other?

Really appreciate any clarification.  Thanks a lot!

First:

```
   var SomeObject;

    SomeObject = (function() {

     function SomeObject() {}

         SomeObject.prototype.doSomething: function() {

         },
         SomeObject.prototype.doSomethingElse: function() {

         }

    })();
```

Second:

```
SomeObject = function() {

 SomeObject.prototype.doSomething: function() {

 },
 SomeObject.prototype.doSomethingElse: function() {

 }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both of those examples are incorrect. I think you meant:

First:

```
var SomeObject;
SomeObject = (function() {

    function SomeObject() {
    }

    SomeObject.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    };

    SomeObject.prototype.doSomethingElse = function() {
    };

    return SomeObject;

})();
```

(Note the return at the end of the anonymous function, the use of `=` rather than `:`, and the semicolons to complete the function assignments.)

Or possibly you meant:

```
function SomeObject() {
}

SomeObject.prototype.doSomething = function() {
};

SomeObject.prototype.doSomethingElse = function() {
};
```

(No anonymous enclosing function.)

Second:

```
function SomeObject() {
}
SomeObject.prototype = {

    doSomething: function() {
    },
    doSomethingElse: function() {
    }
};
```

(Note that the assignment to the prototype is *outside* the `SomeObject` function; here, we use `:` because we're inside an object initializer. And again we have the `;` at the end to complete the assignment statement.)

If I'm correct, there's very little difference between them. Both of them create a `SomeObject` constructor function and add anonymous functions to its prototype. The second version *replaces* the `SomeObject` constructor function's prototype with a completely new object (which I do not recommend), where the first one just augments the prototype that the `SomeObject` constructor function already has.

A more useful form is this:

```
var SomeObject;
SomeObject = (function() {

    function SomeObject() {
    }

    SomeObject.prototype.doSomething = doSomething;
    function doSomething() {

    }

    SomeObject.prototype.doSomethingElse = doSomethingElse;
    function doSomethingElse()
    }

    return SomeObject;

})();
```

There, the functions we assign to `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` have **names**, which is useful when you're walking through code in a debugger (they're shown in call stacks, lists of breakpoints, etc.). The anonymous function wrapping everything is there so that the `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` names don't pollute the enclosing namespace. More: [*Anonymouses anonymous*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html)

Some of us take it further:

```
var SomeObject;
SomeObject = (function() {
    var p = SomeObject.prototype;

    function SomeObject() {
    }

    p.doSomething = SomeObject$doSomething;
    function SomeObject$doSomething() {

    }

    p.doSomethingElse = SomeObject$doSomethingElse;
    function SomeObject$doSomethingElse()
    }

    return SomeObject;

})();
```

...so that not only do we see `doSomething`, but `SomeObject$doSomething` in the lists. Sometimes that can get in the way, though, it's a style choice. (Also note I used the anonymous function to enclose an alias for `SomeObject.prototype`, to make for less typing.)

Comment: Thanks alot, that's a great answer.  You mention debugging, is there an IDE or debugger you recommend for working with JS?

Comment: @dave: Honestly, Chrome's excellent built-in Developer Tools are about all I've needed for most JS debugging.

Comment: @dave: I mean the tools built into most browsers these days (I mostly use Chrome's Dev Tools, or Firefox+Firebug). BTW, if you're interested in the subject of constructor functions, building OOP hierarchies in JavaScript, etc., you might find [my `Lineage` script](http://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/) interesting. It makes some of this easier, while trying to avoid being complex.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder & JackieChiles - Thanks a lot, I always forget you can do more than just console in Developer Tools.  I will definitely checkout the Lineage script - thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

First off, both snippets will not parse for me (Chrome) - you should use `=` in place of `:`. That said, my humble opinion follows.

The latter snippet is slightly strange, because you actually define methods on `SomeObject`'s prototype at the time of the object construction, rather than at the parse time. Thus, if you have re-defined some method on `SomeObject.prototype`, it will get reverted to the original version once a new object is constructed. This may result in unexpected behavior for existing objects of this type.

The former one looks fine, except that the `(function { ...} ())()` wrapper may not be necessary. You can declare just:

```
function SomeObject() {}
SomeObject.prototype.doSomething = function() {}
SomeObject.prototype.doSomethingElse = function() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual difference between first and second in your questions is just:

```
var o = (function () {})();  # call this (A)
```

and

```
var o = function () {};  # call this (B)
```

Unfortunately, *neither* of the examples that you gave are written correctly and, while I don't think either will actually give an error at parse-time, both will break in interesting ways when you try to do things with the result.

To give you an answer about the difference between (A) and (B), (A) is the immediate function application pattern. The JavaScript Patterns book has [a good discussion](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/javascript/9781449399115/functions/immediate_functions), which I recommend.

The actual problems in your code have been explained by other people while I was writing this. In particular T.J. Crowder points out important things.